# Why Lombok annotations seems not work when I try to retrieve object using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, lombok

I am working on a Spring Boot project and I was trying to experiment with Lombok to avoid to define empty boilerplate code such as empty constructor and getter\setter methods in my domain classes.

But it seems not work as I expected.

This is my DTO class:

```
@Getter 
@Setter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class NotaryDistrict {
    
    String idDistrict;
    String denominazione;
    String regione;
    String provincia;
    ArrayList<Localita> localita;
    
    public NotaryDistrict(String idDistrict, String denominazione, String regione, String provincia,
            ArrayList<Localita> localita) {
        super();
        this.idDistrict = idDistrict;
        this.denominazione = denominazione;
        this.regione = regione;
        this.provincia = provincia;
        this.localita = localita;
    }

}
```

As you can see my domain class is annoted using:

- **@NoArgsConstructor**: to avoid to declare the empty constructor.
- **@Getter**: to avoid to declare getter methods.
- **@Setter**: to avoid to declare setter methods.

Then in my code I perform an external API call using **RestTemplate**:

```
ResponseEntity<NotaryDistrict[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(notartelApiUrl, NotaryDistrict[].class);
NotaryDistrict[] notaryDistrictList = response.getBody();
```

So in this case executing the **getForEntity()** method it give me the following error that it is related to the missing empty constructor in the previous domain class:

```
[2m2021-08-06 15:30:24.423[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m9160[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mo.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Encountered an error executing step exampleJobStep in job exampleJob

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.notariato.updateInfo.domain.NotaryDistrict]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.notariato.updateInfo.domain.NotaryDistrict` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:386) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1037) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1020) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:361) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.RESTStudentReader.fetchStudentDataFromAPI(RESTStudentReader.java:105) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.RESTStudentReader.read(RESTStudentReader.java:69) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.RESTStudentReader.read(RESTStudentReader.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.notariato.updateInfo.SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.runSpringBatchExampleJob(SpringBatchExampleJobLauncher.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.notariato.updateInfo.domain.NotaryDistrict` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1764) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1209) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1415) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:362) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:195) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:214) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3601) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.4.jar:2.12.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:378) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

If I now add the empty constructor to the previous domain class (**NotaryDistrict**) I obtain no error. The **getForEntity()** complete but now the object into the retrived array:

```
 NotaryDistrict[] notaryDistrictList = response.getBody();
```

contains empty fields (because it seems that the Lombok **@Setter** and **@Getter** annotation are not working as expected).

If instead I declare the empty constructor and all my getter and setter methods it works as expected and I correctly obtain the array with the field inizitialized as I expected.

Why? What could be the problem? How can I try to fix this behavior?

Comment: Have you installed the Lombok plugin for your IDE?

Comment: How do you run the application? Did the Lombok annotation processor generate the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add lombok dependency to your pom.xml file and configure the java compiler pre-processor to use it when the classes were compiled.

[Adding lombok to your pom file](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven)

Answer (score 0):

Try as following:

- Add following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

- And change your NotaryDistrict class as following

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class NotaryDistrict {
    private String idDistrict;
    private String denominazione;
    private String regione;
    private String provincia;
    private ArrayList<Localita> localita;
}
```

@AllArgsConstructor - declare all args constructor by lombok you don't need to define it.
@Data - define setters, getters, toString(), hascode, equals and RequeiredArgsConstructor

So you don't need to declare them manually.